# How to set subdomain or domain on oracle apex url

Tags: oracle-apex

I configure oracle apex on virtual private hosting & get a domain also.i setup subdomain xyz.abc.com . where can i configure the subdomain for access my oracle apex using the subdomain over internet.?

Answer (score 0):

Create and Point the A record in your domain settings to the IP of your server.

There is no configuration in APEX whatsoever. The resolution is at the domain level.